# Multiple color fonts in one html email

Tags: c#, html, input

mailItem.HTMLBody = "

Dear IT Dept.

You have received a new "+  comboBox3.Text  + " priority task to complete from " + textBox1.Text + ". Please save the attached file and fit the task in to your schedule.

Once completed please contact the " + textBox2.Text + " for comfirmation the task is completed to thier expectations.

The Task is as follows:

" + richTextBox1.Text + "

Kind Regards,

" + textBox1.Text + "

";

I basically want to highlight the text/combo boxes or at least change their font color. Annoyingly you can't see the html code I used but it should be pretty obvious but I tried using the font color...with no luck. can't see where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you try to put value of `textBox2.txt`. Your mistake is that wrote textBox2.txt as a string content. So you can achive this with using `string.Format` method.

**You should to change it with this:**

```
  mailItem.HTMLBody = string.Format("<html><body><p>Dear IT Dept.</p> <p>You have         received a new task to complete from ({0}) Please check the attached file and     fit the task in to your schedule.</p><p> Once completed please contact the provided contactee for comfirmation the task is completed to thier expectations.</p>", textBox2.Text);
```

Notice that `textBox2.Text and` `{0}` element.
Note: You also wrong with syntax of TextBox.Text property.

Comment: Thank you! to add multiple would I increment the number so {0} would be {1} and then define the second string behind the first at the end?

Comment: Yes. For detail check this page http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format. By the way, do not forget to make me happy with marked as accepted answer my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have:

```
mailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>... from " + textBox2.Text + " Please ...";
```

instead of

```
mailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>... from (textBox2.txt) Please ...";
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `HTMLBody` property on the `MailMessage` class (assuming this is what you're using?).

It's just [Body](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.body(v=vs.110).aspx).

You would do something like this:

```
 mailItem.Body = string.Format("<html><body><p>Dear {0}.</p>", comboBox3.Text);
```

Etc...

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean :

```
mailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body><p>Dear IT Dept.</p> <p>You have         received a new task to complete from " + textBox2.Text + " Please check the attached file and     fit the task in to your schedule.</p><p> Once completed please contact the provided contactee for comfirmation the task is completed to thier expectations.</p>";
```

?

In your version, "textbox2.txt" will be manipulated as a string, it won't be "parsed".
In mine it's a control on your form and we put its text content in the mail.

Edit : you asked how to emphase the variable, here is a example :
Try something like

```
mailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body><p>Dear IT Dept.</p> <p>You have received a new task to complete from <strong>" + textBox2.Text + "</strong> Please check the attached file and fit the task in to your schedule.</p><p> Once completed please contact the provided contactee for comfirmation the task is completed to thier expectations.</p>";
```

The "strong" tag around your variable will put the name in bold.

Comment: Thanks buddy, looks like the simplest way!

Comment: Do you know how I would highlight the variables or change the text color for them so they stand out in the email?

Comment: In html ? I've edited my answer above to put a sample. Don't hesitate to up vote my answer as it was helpful. Good luck

Comment: I wish I could buddy but don't have 15 reputation to do so yet :(

Answer (score 0):

```
                var mailItem= new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp server addess");

                mailItem.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@xyz.com");
                mailItem.To.Add("it-department@???.co.uk");


                    mailItem.Subject = string.Format("You have a new task from {0}", comboBox3.Text);
                    mailItem.To = "";
                    mailItem.Body =string.Format("<html><body><p>Dear IT Dept.</p> <p>You have         received a new task to complete from {0} Please check the attached file and     fit the task in to your schedule.</p><p> Once completed please contact the provided contactee for comfirmation the task is completed to their expectations.</p>",textBox2.txt);

                    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(@"\\??-filesvr\shares\Shared\+++++Web Projects+++++\????\IssueReport.txt");
                    mailItem.Attachments.Add(@"\\??-filesvr\shares\Shared\+++++Web Projects+++++\??\IssueReport.txt");

                    mailItem.IsBodyHtml = true;

                // Optional Items based on your smtp server.
                /* SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;*/

                SmtpServer.Send(mailItem);
                MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
```